# How to achieve this text skew effect?

Tags: text, affinity-designer, skew

I am trying to achieve a specific text skew effect (see pictures below). I am using Affinity Designer 2. I tried following methods:

- Warp Group - Perspective (doesn't work because the font weight of some characters visually changes)
- Manually stretch each character using nodes

I am wondering if a different font would solve the situation, or if I should somehow transform even the *O* and *D* characters (which I've also tried, unsuccessfully).

Following pictures represent what I am trying to achieve and what I got so far:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to get a little closer than your previous attempt is to use Layer > Warp Group > Perspective in Affinity Designer version 2:

[image]

The words are separate objects and they are both their own perspective warp groups. Move the corner points with the node tool for a good perspective.

In your goal example this works well for the word PISMO. The letters get smaller in the right end in both dimensions. But the lower word is different (as you already have noticed), because the letters look like they keep their horizontal thicknesses. Perspective would make the lower word (and FOOD in my example above) to look tenuous.

The fix is easy. You can use warp "Quad" instead of "Perspective". See the next example:

[image]

In the left both words have got the perspective warp as in my 1st example.  In the middle both words have got the quad warp. The rightmost version is a combination. TASTY has got the perspective warp and FOOD has got the quad warp. Only an opinion, but the combination version looks somehow more balanced than the others.

**Warning:** The program has a weakness. Warped texts get easily trashed if you move them. To make them solid normal objects select the warp group in the Layers panel and apply Convert to Curves. Texts and warps lose their editability, but now the items can be selected and moved easily by clicking and dragging. Better to have an editable spare copy, too.

A warp group can be moved if one selects it as a whole in the layers panel. To select it all collapse the group and click the warp group icon. Otherwise something stays unselected and moving causes unpredictable distortion. This happens in A.D. version 2.1.0. Maybe it gets better in later versions.